# How to invoke component to update data?

Tags: rest, angular

I have a main component with 2 sub-components (update, profile).

On update component, I have a form with several input fields. When I submit a form, profile section information should update after a successful request.

The problem is, profile information doesn't update after a successful request.

So, how to invoke profile component to refresh updated data? I tried to call a service after successful request, but no luck.

By the way, parent service looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class AvailabilityService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getProfile() {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + '/user/profile')
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  freeOwnersParking(availableDates: AvailableDates) {
    let domain = API_URL + '/parking/availability';
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify(availableDates);
    return this.http.put(domain, body, options)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body;
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Get profile:

```
getProfile() {
    this.availabilityService.getProfile()
      .subscribe(
        profile =>this.profile = profile,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
  }
```

Update profile:

```
freeOwnersParking() {
    this.availabilityService.freeOwnersParking(this.availableDates)
      .subscribe(
        response => this.availabilityService.getProfile(),
        error => this.errorMessage = error
      );
  }
```

Comment: There is nothing to do except updating the values. Your question doesn't show how you do it. How are you using the service in your component and what data doesn't update?

Comment: You have to subscribe to getProfile() method in your coponent. That way you will be able to bind profile data to form...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage a shared service between them to notify the profile component.

For example an UpdateProfileService with an observable / subject in it. In this case, the profile component can subscribe on it to be notified.

Here is the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UpdateProfileService {
  profileUpdated:Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  (...)

  updateProfile(profile:any) {
    return this.http.put('http://...', profile)
            .map(res => {
              this.profileUpdated.next(true);
              return res.json();
            });
  }
}
```

and within the profile component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class ProfileComponent {
  constructor(private service:UpdateProfileService) {
    this.service.profileUpdated.subscribe(() => {
      // Update bound data for profile
    });
  }
}
```